# What does "… coach and six, or his own coach and sixty" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> So with the three passengers shut up in the narrow compass of one lumbering old mail coach; they were mysteries to one another, as complete as if each had been in his own coach and **six**, or his own coach ***and sixty***, with the breadth of a county between him and the next.

What does the term *six* and *and sixty* in the preceding sentence from Dickens's *[A Tale of Two Cities](https://www.dickens-online.info/a-tale-of-two-cities-page6.html)* mean?

Comment: A cursory internet search leads one to a plethora of information about this. Have you done that?

Answer (score 5):

Six horses!

A private coach drawn by six horses would be the ultimate in expensive fast travel. The idea of using sixty horses is obviously [hyperbole](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyperbole).

Comment: I suppose a 'coach and sixty' means that they'll never be caught / inconvenienced by an unwanted encounter.